# Android: get flash drive's mountpoint from USB enumeration point

Tags: android, linux, usb-drive, mount-point

I have a flash drive where I know its vendor ID and product ID.

By scanning through `/sys/bus/usb/devices`, I can reliably find the enumeration point for the root device (e.g. `/sys/bus/usb/devices/3-1`) and the enumeration point for the mass storage device (e.g. `/sys/bus/usb/devices/3-1:1.0`).

**Once I know the two enumeration points, how do I use these to lookup the mountpoint (e.g. `/mnt/usb0/part0` or `/mnt/UsbStorageA`)?**

--

**Alternatively, is there a direct way to get the mountpoint from the vendor ID and product ID?**

--

**EDIT 1 (more details on my progress):**

Ok so (working backward from the mountpoint):

mountpoint: `/storage/usb0/part0` (according to `/proc/mount`)

device node: `/dev/block/vold/8:1` (according to `/proc/mount`)

partition name `sda1` (according to `/proc/partitions`)

But I can't seem to correlate into `/sys/block`, because there is no `sda1` entry in `/sys/block`, and neither is there any `8:1` entry in `/sys/dev/block`. Instead, bizarrely, the USB device is in `/sys/dev/char`, as `189:261`. Why the heck would it appear as a char device but not a block device? :-(

Comment: If this was normal linux, you could run `/bin/mount` to see what's currently mounted.  I'm not sure that's the best way under Android...

Comment: You can get the same effect by reading `/proc/mount` (exact same info to the character), but that still doesn't mention vendor ID, product ID, or enumeration point - how do I tell which mounted device is the right one?

Comment: Hmm.  Read the mounts, map that to the list of stuff in `/sys/block`, which includes device IDs?  The things in `/sys/bus/devices` point to the same place as those in `/sys/block`...

Comment: Typed a big comment in response but instead I've posted it as EDIT 1, so please see that. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Quote "There are two directories, 'block' and 'char', beneath /sys/dev containing symbolic links with names of the form "<major>:<minor>".  These links point to the corresponding sysfs path for the given device."

Comment: Yes, this is correct. I can follow "forward" from the vid and pid to  /sys/dev. Or I can follow "backward" from mountpoint to /dev. But I can't "jump the gap" between /sys/dev and /dev no matter what I try.